# iPhone Simulator: App/Documents disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, documents, gh-unit

Is it standard that a XCode-Build empties the documents folder of the app on iphone simulator?

How can I prevent that?

Comment: No it should not, unless use the `Reset Content & Settings...` or remove your app.

Comment: This was related to GHViewTestCase and the images it saves. I figured on the GHUnit documentation that I have to use some Script magic that ships with GHUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when ever you re-build the application or make any other application with same app id ,the document folder for that is not erased .It will be removed only when the app is removed from the simulator.